# ggplot heat map with geom_tile using weight for fill color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get a heat map using three variables: Discrete (x,y) for coordinates and a z which is a weight. I want bins/tiles to have colors depending on the sum. I get a decent result as follows:

```
x = c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12)
y = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6)
z = c(1, 4, 2, 2, 8, 8)

dd <- data.frame(x,y,z)
p <- ggplot(dd, aes(x=x,y=y,weight=z)) + 
  stat_bin2d(bins=c(5,4))
p
```

[image]

It's not exactly what I want, since the bins are squeezed into a space that's not really big enough and they're not centered onto the coordinates.

I discovered `geom_tile` which seems to be the way to go, except I can't figure out how to get the `fill` color to be based on the weight (summed z for each bin) as it worked with `stat_bin2d`. The following uses a fill based on `z` but isn't the sum. You can see the difference in the value of the (12,6) bin which is 8 rather than 16.

```
    p <- ggplot(dd, aes(x=x,y=y,weight=z)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill=z))  + 
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "steelblue")
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using factors will center the tiles with `stat_bin_2d`:

```
p <- ggplot(dd, aes(x=as.factor(x),y=as.factor(y),weight=z)) + 
  stat_bin2d()
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would preprocess the data to calculate the sums

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  summarise(z = sum(z)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z)) + 
    geom_tile()  + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "steelblue")
```